# append XML literal to DOMDocument in php without escaping

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a string that represents nodes I'd like to append to a DOMDocument in PHP, but when I add it as a value to an element, it gets escaped.  Is there a way to append a chunk of XML to a DOMDocument without it getting escaped - and with the one string addition, several nodes getting added?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$string = <<<XML
    <myNode>
        <OtherNode>value</OtherNode>
    </myNode>
XML;

$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xml_id = $domDoc->createElement('mydata');
        $value = $domDoc->createTextNode($string);
        $xml_id->appendChild($value);
        $subNode = $domDoc->appendChild($xml_id);

echo $domDoc->saveXML();
```

Currently, however the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mydata>    &lt;myNode&gt;
        &lt;OtherNode&gt;value&lt;/OtherNode&gt;
    &lt;/myNode&gt;</mydata>
```

Is there a way to make it look like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mydata>
    <myNode>
        <OtherNode>value</OtherNode>
    </myNode>
</mydata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm not incorrect, you actually should create a `documentFragment` and append the XML literal to that. Then you should append the documentFragment to the `$xml_id` and then you should append `$xml_id` to the `$domDoc`

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xml_id = $domDoc->createElement('mydata');
$frag = $domDoc->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($string);

$xml_id->appendChild($frag);
$domDoc->appendChild($xml_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  That's exactly what I needed!